# How do I get 4 instead of 4.0 in "Squirrels and nuts - 1" task?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, modulo

> **Squirrels and nuts - 1**
>
> N squirrels found K nuts and decided to divide them equally. Determine
>   how many nuts each squirrel will get.
>
> **Input data format**
>
> There are two positive numbers N and K, each of them is not greater
>   than 10000.
>
> ---
>
> **Sample Input:**
>   3
>   14
>
> ---
>
> **Sample Output:**
>   4

```
>>> squirrels = 3
>>> nuts = 14
>>> extra_nuts = 14 % 3
>>> distributable_nuts = nuts - extra_nuts 
>>> nuts_per_squirrel = distributable_nuts / squirrels
>>> print(nuts_per_squirrel)
4.0
```

I am not sure why my answer is not correct. Right now I get `4.0` but it should be `4`.  Any guidance would be helpful. I had used `%` to remove the extra nuts to make them evenly distributable across 3 squirrels, but `4.0` wasn't correct.

Comment: Please read this guide on [asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a float result, use integer division: `//` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nuts` value is set to 14. Divided by three that's 4.6 when it's expecting 4.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that lack a *text* [mcve], it only encourages more of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since 14 does not divide by three equally, you are receiving a floating point number. You can cast this to an integer to disregard the remainder by `int(nuts_per_squirrel)`.

Comment: Whether the type of the result is floating-point or integer is decided by the operator (`//` for integer or `/`) and the types of the operands, whether the numerator is a multiple of the denominator.